# Fetching details from CUSTOM_META table using DD4T

Tags: content-delivery, dd4t

I have a Schema where I store the following information (as Metadata):

1. Event date
2. Latitude
3. Longitude

When I publish a Component using this Schema, the information getting stored in the Custom_Meta Table in the Broker database is in the following format:

[image: Custom_Meta Table sample content]

I would like to group this data based on ITEM_ID and retrieve the details in the following format using DD4T:

[image: desired grouped results]

Would this be possible using DD4T and the Tridion.ContentDelivery.dll's?

Comment: Is this metadata then? If you query for components using the DD4T library each component will carry its own metadata available to you through the model.

Comment: Neil I got what you are trying to explain, the purpose we dont what to go through the Component model is it going to take a long time to retrieve, if the records are huge(as in my case).

Comment: @KarthikRaghavan indeed tables are not (easily) possible in a question, but you could have written the text and just used images for the tables as I have done just now. That makes it a lot more accessible for everybody, please keep that in mind for your future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could turn this around and do your heavy-lifting on the CM side instead of runtime.

1. You have your data in the Content Manager
2. You create a "special" page with a "special" Page Template
3. In the Page Template logic you loop through all the components of that type and gather all the data you need, and store it in a format (XML? JSON?) that your application can load easily and efficiently.
4. You add a business rule (or event system) that every time you update this data, this page gets republished (or perhaps only republish once every 4 hours).
5. Your application can now load this data from a structured data file in one go instead of having to query the database and format the data for your specific needs.

PS - I still think you should remove that image from here.

Comment: Even we where thinking about this as an alternative approach. Thanks a lot Nuno

Comment: I will remove it out ASAP

Answer (score 3):

This is not a DD4T question. Querying the broker for custom metadata or other types of metadata is a feature of the Tridion broker.

Normally, such broker queries return a list of TCM URIs. You can then use the DD4T ComponentFactory to retrieve an object representing each of the matching components.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand that you want a list of all Component Presentations using that certain Schema from the Broker, you could use the following code sample for that:

```cs
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string templateUri = "tcm:1-7-32";
int publicationId = 1;
int schemaId = 5;

using (ComponentPresentationAssembler cpa = new ComponentPresentationAssembler("tcm:0-0-0", Page))
using (ComponentPresentationFactory cpf = new ComponentPresentationFactory(publicationId))
{
  Criteria itemTypeCriteria = new ItemTypeCriteria(16);
  Criteria schemaCriteria = new ItemSchemaCriteria(schemaId);
  AndCriteria criteria = new AndCriteria(itemTypeCriteria, schemaCriteria);
  Query query = new Query(criteria);
  foreach (string uri in query.ExecuteQuery())
  {
    using (ComponentPresentation cp = cpf.GetComponentPresentation(uri, templateUri))
    {
      if (cp != null)
      {
        // use ComponentPresentationAssembler since cp.Content does not resolve REL
        sb.Append(cpa.GetContent(string.Format("tcm:{0}-{1}", 
                                               publicationId, 
                                               cp.ComponentId), 
                                 string.Format("tcm:{0}-{1}-32", 
                                               publicationId, 
                                               cp.ComponentTemplateId)));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This sample is getting a list of all Components in the Broker based on your Schema and then get the Component Presentations available for those. Depending on your requirements, you could perhaps use `cp.Content` instead of using the `ComponentPresentationAssembler`, but this should give you a general idea of how to query the Broker.